# gfortran: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory in build with MinGW

Tags: dll, mingw, gfortran, lapack, mingw-w64

I tried to build shared lib for Lapack with MinGW_64. I got error as 
`gfortran: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory`.

My Lapack version is Lapack_3.5 and my MinGW has x86_64-4.9.2-posix-seh-rt_v3-rev1 version for x86_64.

I can build blas.dll with `gfortran --shared -o blas.dll blas\src\*.f -O` successfully. But when I build lapack.dll with `gfortran --shared -o lapack.dll src\*.f blas.dll -O`, I got `gfortran: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory` error. I have restarted the system after MinGW's installation.

Comment: When linking to the blas DLL, you need something in the form of `-lblas`. Now you're just adding the blas.dll file as a source file or object file to be linked, which is weird, because a shared library is not an object file.

Comment: let me test.but I think it is not the issue

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to an error in the mingw package you are using.  The same thing happened to me.

If you search for a *gfortran*.exe file under your mingw tree (x86_mingw*gfortran*.exe or whatever - I don't have the machine this happend on any more), you can invoke this with the full pathname.  This should work.